# Changing the SwiftData object by copy in func

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

As far as I know, any object is passed to a function by copying unless inout is specified

This is how it always worked until I started integrating SwiftData into my app

#### There is the following code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct AccountCircleList: View {
        
    @Query var accounts: [Account]
    @Query var currencies: [Currency]
    
    var groupedAccounts: [Account] {
        return groupAccounts(accounts: tmp, currencies: currencies)
    }
    ...
}

// addictional Q: Maybe there is a way not to transmit exchange currencies directly?
func groupAccounts(accounts: [Account], currencies: [Currency]) -> [Account] {

    /////// this is just illustrative example

    // Before it was "Cash"
    print(accounts[0].name)
    accounts[0].name += "Some" // After this I see "CashSomeSomeSomeSome..." in console

    ///////
    
    var ratesMap: [String: Decimal] {
        Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: currencies.map { ($0.isoCode, $0.rate ) })
    }
        
    for (i, account) in accounts.enumerated() {
        if let parentAccountID = account.parentAccountID {
            let parentAccountIndex = accounts.firstIndex { $0.id == parentAccountID }
            let parentAccount = accounts[parentAccountIndex!]
            
            if account.visible {
                // Here we change the value of the array in usual case
                accounts[parentAccountIndex!].childrenAccounts.append(account)
                if account.accounting {
                    let relation = (ratesMap[parentAccount.currency] ?? 1) / (ratesMap[account.currency] ?? 1)
                    accounts[parentAccountIndex!].budget += account.budget * relation
                    accounts[parentAccountIndex!].remainder += account.remainder * relation
                }
            }
            accounts[i].isChild = true // And here
        }
    }
    return accounts
}
```

> This function groups child accounts into parent accounts and calculates the overall statistics

But it turns out that it changes the overall accounts array, which triggers the grouping function again and again, infinitely, until the memory runs out

Would there be any possibility to do `var accountsCopy = accounts.copy()`

#### **What I tried:**

- I tried making a subView and calling the `groupAccounts()` function from it, but it resulted in the same result
- Assign another variable to accounts in a function and change it: `var tmp = accounts`
- Also I make another class `Account2` with same fields and convert `accounts` to `accounts2` in func, it helped but it looks ugly

#### What I expect:

Behavior in which the function will not change the original array and the function will be called only once when opening the screen or changing data in the database

Comment: Hi, in Swift, structs and "basic types" such as `Int` are passed as a copy, objects are passed by reference. Could that be the issue? I don't see a definition for `Account` in your code, if it's a `class`, objects created from it would be passed by reference.

Comment: @Baglan Hi, yes, this is true, but even if I do `var tmp = accounts`, thereby copying the original `accounts` class, and change `tmp`, then the data in the database still changes and again begins to cyclically change itself. It looks like the swiftData model has a reference type field inside it (like in Go, for example), and when we copy the original object, the memory reference in the database is copied to the new object, not its value

Comment: @Baglan each element of the `accounts` array has a `_$backingData` field, which, as far as I know, is a reference to a memory location and is copied when assigned to another variable, because the first `tmp` element has the same `backing` address as and the first element `accounts`. How can I make a copy of accounts and change it so as not to change the actual `accounts` array in the database. I don't rule out that I have the wrong approach

Comment: @Baglan I just want to make a flat data array into a tree view with aggregation of some fields for one View, but due to my actions I am causing a cyclic recalculation of the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of my problem was the `@transient` attribute, which says to SwiftData to ignore this field, thereby making the `childrenAccounts` field with this at attribute and adding two new `aggregatedBudget` and `aggregatedRemainder`, I can’t change the “sensitive” data that SwiftData reacts

```
@Transient var childrenAccounts: [Account] = []
@Transient var aggregatedBudget: Decimal = 0
@Transient var aggregatedRemainder: Decimal = 0
```

Comment: I must admit, I'm not a SwiftData master by any measure, I thought about `@Transient` too :). While "caching" calculation results in a data model doesn't feel right, it's a very practical thing to do. Based on your code, I have a hunch that the account hierarchy only goes one level down (children don't have children of their own), otherwise, aggregated balance calculations could easily be incorrect. Personally, I would consider making another model for parent account or some sort of a helper model that would have parent and children fields.

Comment: As a side note, I've also tried to extend a model to make another model (ParentAccount would be an extension of the basic Account), at the first glance, @Model is not designed for that :)

Comment: @Baglan Yes, this is true, in my case, I have a maximum of one level of investment, in the case of a multi -sized level, I will either have to make recursive logic in the Groupaccounts functions, or rebuild the data model